# Pad middle values based on previouse and next values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I've df Like this

```
   col     col2
0    0  Repeat1
1    3  Repeat2
2    5  Repeat3
3    7  Repeat4
4    9  Repeat5
```

Reproducable

```
L= [0,3,5,7,9]
L2 = ['Repeat1','Repeat2','Repeat3','Repeat4','Repeat5']

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})
df['col2']= L2
print (df)
```

How can fill missing intermidaite values such that my df will looks like this

```
  col     col2
0    0  Repeat1
1    1  Repeat1
2    2  Repeat1
3    3  Repeat2
4    4  Repeat2
5    5  Repeat3
6    6  Repeat3
7    7  Repeat4
8    8  Repeat4
9    9  Repeat5
```

Similar threads I've tried

[Filling missing middle values in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821653/filling-missing-middle-values-in-pandas-dataframe) (Filling Nan values for intermediate values but I don't need Nan)

[Fill pandas dataframe with values in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798076/fill-pandas-dataframe-with-values-in-between) (Very Big approch. I'm looking any functional appraoch)

Both cases helped me some extent But i was wondering is any ways to do it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also `merge` and `ffill`

```
(df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'col': range(df['col'].max()+1)}), how='right')
       .ffill()
    )
```

Output:

```
   col     col2
0    0  Repeat1
1    1  Repeat1
2    2  Repeat1
3    3  Repeat2
4    4  Repeat2
5    5  Repeat3
6    6  Repeat3
7    7  Repeat4
8    8  Repeat4
9    9  Repeat5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) with "col" as temporary index:

```
out = (df.set_index('col')
         .reindex(range(df['col'].max()+1))
         .ffill()
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   col     col2
0    0  Repeat1
1    1  Repeat1
2    2  Repeat1
3    3  Repeat2
4    4  Repeat2
5    5  Repeat3
6    6  Repeat3
7    7  Repeat4
8    8  Repeat4
9    9  Repeat5
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway ..How to do if my col has duplicate values? I can't use this If I've duplicate values It's throwing `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`

Comment: @Bhargav what would be the expected behavior then? Can you provide another example? (almost) Everything is possible but you have to clearly define the rules ;)

Comment: I'm sorry updating...

Comment: I'm figuring out myself @mozway ..I will reach out if I fail to figure it out myself.. :D

Comment: @Bhargav sure, no worries (it's always better to try to scratch one's own itches, best way to learn!)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'col': range(df['col'].max()+1)}),
            df.set_index('col')], axis=1).ffill()
```

---

Or, alternatively:

```
(pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(
    {'col': list(set(range(1, df.col.max()+1)).difference(df.col))})])
 .sort_values('col').ffill().reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

Output:

```
   col     col2
0    0  Repeat1
1    1  Repeat1
2    2  Repeat1
3    3  Repeat2
4    4  Repeat2
5    5  Repeat3
6    6  Repeat3
7    7  Repeat4
8    8  Repeat4
9    9  Repeat5
```